# Multiple Layers of Matching Blank Cells

Tags: google-sheets

I'm back with another Google Sheets question. This one isn't scripting though - this time I'm looking for help in figuring out a formula.

I've attached screenshots of two sheets. The first one features one "opposing party" at row 8. The second one features an opposing part at row 8 and a second opposing party at row 9. Cell B3's formula is shown in both; in essence, Cell B3 looks for the first blank cell in column L after Row 10 (or Row 11 in the second image) and returns the contents of that row's "F" column. This allows me to "get" the next deadline in the matter that is being tracked. For those interested, yes, Cell D3 has a similar formula looking at K.

[image: One Opposing Party]

[image: Two Opposing Parties]

Currently, we have to manually update B3 (and D3) if we add additional parties (not necessarily opposing, and not just one either). This is more tedious than I would like. I would like a formula that would return "F10" and "L10" in situations where only one opposing party appears, "F11" and "L11" if there is an additional, and so on so that even if we have a massive, multi-party action it will still return the next cell.

If it helps, you can always assume that there will be a blank set of cells below the last "opposing party" and the row that we want to start querying (as shown in the second image).

I'd love any help that you can give. Please let me know if you need anything clarified.

Thanks a ton!

--Databoy2k

Comment: a) do you want column K or column L (i.e. K10/K11or L10/L11)? b) Why can't you match the header label and offset? c) I must be over-complicating as I just don't understand what your end goal is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you require for B3?

```
=index(F:F, match("rule", I:I, 0)+1)
```

[image]

In a larger scope use,

```
=index(indirect("F"&match("Rule",I:I,0)&":F"), match(TRUE, index(isblank(indirect("L"&match("Rule",I:I,0)&":L")),0,0),0))
```

Comment: Right idea - I hadn't thought to look for "Rule". I need to combine that with the existing formula in B3, though, so that B3 also looks for the first empty cell in K after the results of your formula. I need to convert the part below in square brackets into an actual spreadsheet formula: =index(['F'+match("Rule",I;I,0)+':F'], match(TRUE, index(isblank(['L'+match("Rule",I:I,0)+':L']),0,0),))). Maybe concatenate would work?

Comment: indirect("'F"&match("Rule",I;I,0)&":F") but there must be a better way.

Comment: To follow up on the concatenate thought, I set this up but it isn't working: =index(concatenate("F",match("Rule",I:I,0),":F"), match(TRUE, index(isblank(concatenate("L",match("Rule",I:I,0),":L")),0,0),0))

Comment: indirect("'F"&match("Rule",I;I,0)&":F")

Comment: Genius. Please paste this into an answer so that I can mark it and give you the credit. =index(indirect("F"&match("Rule",I:I,0)&":F"), match(TRUE, index(isblank(indirect("L"&match("Rule",I:I,0)&":L")),0,0),0))

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to make the cells you are referencing a named range.  That way, you can add as many other rows, columns, cells, whatever, and your formula will always reference the same range of cells.

For example, you could name the range of cells in column F 'Steps', and in K 'Deadline', then change your formula to `=index(Steps,match(TRUE, index(isblank(Deadline),0,0),0))`, and it will always give you the correct range.

Here's a pic to show how to name a range (right-click on the selection).

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but I really can't do named ranges. There are ~60 of these sheets (differently named, different contents, but matching this format) at any point in time, the timelines are generated by scripts, are copied and pasted around, and even naming the "entities" would require the named range to be resized.

Comment: Is it possible to start all new sheets from a template?  That way when changes are made, the ranges and formulas are already in place.  "even naming the "entities" would require the named range to be resized." - does this mean that you add/delete rows in the 'Litigation steps' table?

Comment: Yes; the "Litigation Steps" table is frequently changed, and sometimes other tables are inserted above it. That's why I'd like to look for that blank row below "opposing party", maybe offset by a row, and then look for my blank cell in K.